# Would random BIGINT used as a primary key significantly affect performance?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Background:

I'm trying to find the best way to store IDs in APIs. UUID got a lot of performance-related issues, and incremental IDs are not safe in some cases. After experimenting with different approaches I found random `BIGING` ([PHP example](https://github.com/firevel/model-random-id/blob/master/src/HasRandomId.php)) the best compromise between performance and uniqueness.

Question:

Would random `BIGINT` (example 9007199254740991) used as a primary key, affect significantly query performance when it comes to operations like joins?

On small databases, it performs well but I never had a chance to test it on large production databases.

Answer (score 0):

Primary key is normally used as clustered index, so if your identifiers are not sorted (i.e. default autoincrement IS sorted), you'll get performance problems on insertion.
Joins should not be affected.
BTW, as for UUID - again it's not sorted, but there's algorithm to have UUID partly random generated, partly built from current time, and then it is sorted.

What do you mean, simple auto-increment is not safe? What safety do you need?

Comment: Auto-increment issues:
- It might expose business data (for example some companies might not want to expose the number of orders).
- Merging databases is a nightmare (when you got multiple instances of code running, and trying to merge them into one).
- In some cases, you can brute-force confidential data (usually cause by programmer error).

Comment: Example of auto-increment abuse:
A non-senior developer built a system where platform users can send messages between each other. Because API had syntax like /users/{id}/messages it was very simple to send spam to all users. If a unique identifier is used, the same implementation would be fairly secure.

Comment: Well, then Bigint will not guarantee safety as well. In case you are thinking of merging databases, etc. Try using time ordered UUIDs. So you will have fast insert, joins will be fast by indexes and it is pretty safe no conflict appear. https://uuid.ramsey.dev/en/latest/nonstandard/version6.html

Comment: The probability of randomly generating two equal 16 digits numbers is less likely than the probability of someone entering a record into the wrong database and causing merge conflict. It's more important to have good collision handling than a pseudo-guarantee of having unique ids in each database.